# Не находит элемент массива

Tags: php

Добрый день, ребят. Есть массив, назовем его `UserArticleList`, вот его вардамп:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(1) "1" 
[1]=> string(1) "2" 
}
```

Есть такой кусочек кода:

```
foreach($ArticleList as $article){
          if(array_search($article['id'],$UserArticleList)){
            continue;
             //Продолжаем обрабатывать запись
          }
```

Здесь циклом перебираются все записи бд(`$ArticleListas`). Если `id` текущей записи есть в массиве, то переходим к следующей итерации цикла. И все должно бы работать, но `array_search` находит только элемент со значением `2`. Почему?)

Comment: в цикле сделайте tcho $article['id']....   что выводит? точно разные ID из базы?

Comment: @Arsen, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Arsen выводит 2, да, id разные, там 2 записи, я вардампил, у них id =1 и 2)

Comment: @Arsen, а если вывести id до проверки на наличие такового в массиве, то выводит оба, первый и второй(1 , 2). С Id все в норме.

Comment: так вы по ключу ищите или по значению ??

Comment: @Arsen, по значению

Comment: написал ответ с примером

Comment: @Arsen, да, жду когда можно будет его отметить как правильный. Всем спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В **[доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)** написано, что:

> **Внимание**
>   Эта функция может возвращать как boolean FALSE, так и не-boolean значение, которое приводится к FALSE. За более подробной информацией обратитесь к разделу Булев тип. **Используйте оператор ===** для проверки значения, возвращаемого этой функцией.

Соответственно, когда попадается первый элемент, возвращается ключ под номером 0. И в виду неявного преобразования 0 в булев тип, получается конструкция вот такого вида:

```
if (false) { ....
```

вот он и не находит ничего.

Следовательно. Надо писать либо так:

```
if(array_search($article['id'],$UserArticleList) !== false){...
```

либо использовать `in_array`:

```
if(in_array($article['id'],$UserArticleList)){...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($ArticleList as $article){    
    if(in_array($article['id'],$UserArticleList)){
        do some...
    }
}
```

Если также необходимо сравнивать типы, добавьте true:

```
in_array($article['id'],$UserArticleList,true)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: Завсегда пожалуйста ;)

Answer (score 3):

А что вам мешает использовать `in_array` ?

```
<?php
foreach($ArticleList as $article){
    if(in_array($article['id'],$UserArticleList)){
    continue;
     //Продолжаем обрабатывать запись
    }

?>
```